# Não encontra string dentro um array com BufferedReader

Tags: java

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação que permite ao utilizador introduzir duas cidades e depois verificar num array com as "Cidades" já existentes, se essas que o utilizador introduzir existem.

O problema, é quando tento ler a cidade que o utilizador quer procura com o BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Cidade1:");
    String cidade1 = "Santo Tirso";//br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Cidade2:");
    String cidade2 ="Felgueiras";// br.readLine();
**//desta maneira funciona, mas se colocar o readLine já nao encontra as cidades**
```

ele não encontra as cidades, mas se colocar como o código em cima, sem pedir ao utilizador que introduza dados então ele encontra.

Em baixo, mostro o método completo:

```
public void menuCidades() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Introduza as cidades:\n");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Cidade1:");
    String cidade1 = "Santo Tirso";//br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Cidade2:");
    String cidade2 ="Felgueiras";// br.readLine();

    int cidade1w = getIDCidade((T) cidade1);
    int cidade2w = getIDCidade((T) cidade2);

    if (cidade1w != -1 && cidade2w != -1) {
        System.out.println("teste de entrar");
        // calcularPercursos_Parametros((T) cidade1w, (T) cidade2w);
    }
```

Já tentei com o debugger, mas não entendo qual seja o problema!
Deverá ser algum erro de principiante e não estou conseguir indentificar!

**EDIT**

Método getIdCidade:

```
 public int getIDCidade(T cidade) {
    int id = -1;
    String cidadec = (String) cidade;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.conjuntoCidades.length; i++) {

        if (this.conjuntoCidades[i] == cidadec) {
            id = i;

        }
    }
    return id;
}
```

Debuug com Buffer:
[image: Aqui mostro o debugg com o Buffer, as cidades estão iguais]

Comment: O que é aquele cast `(T)` no método getIDCidade? Como você está comparando (checando se estão no array) as cidades? Se for com `equals` ou `==` você tem que digitar o nome da cidade EXATAMENTE como está no array.

Comment: @Genos adicionei esse método para vocês ver a implementação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o método equals para fazer comparações estre objetos.

Seu método ficaria assim.

```
public int getIDCidade(T cidade) {
    int id = -1;
    String cidadec = (String) cidade;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.conjuntoCidades.length; i++) {

        if (this.conjuntoCidades[i].equals(cidadec)) {
            id = i;

        }
    }
    return id;
}
```

Acredito que vocês esta populando o conjuntoCidades inline com strings estaticas, por isso que o == funciona quando o nome da cidade e colocado direto no código fonte, o java é inteligente o suficiente para não criar dois objetos String estáticos com o mesmo valor, com isso quando você coloca dois "Santo Tirso" no código fonte o java cria apenas um objeto na memoria fazendo o == retornar true.

De uma olhada nesse tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, Henrique!